# Pass and modify the output of one method before sending it to another

Tags: linux, bash

Is there a way to modify the output of a command before piping it to another method?

For example:

```
print_log_message()
{
  echo "A descriptive log message"
}

print_error_message()
{
  echo "A descriptive error message"
}

log()
{
  logger -s $1
}
```

I would like a message to be logged in the format: 
"Log message: A descriptive log message"

However the prefix "Log message:" may change.

```
print_log_message > log "Log message: ${log_output}"

print_error_message > log "Error message: ${error_output}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this will really answer your question, but I had a similar problem recently. I don't know about a '>' redirection but I can offer two possibilities.

First using a pipe ('|'):

```
log(){
  while read msg
  do
    echo "$1: $msg"
  done
}

echo "all is fine" | log "Log message"
# Log message: all is fine
echo "drama!" | log "Error message"
# Error message: drama!
```

But I am not sure why you need to use stdin, maybe it's mandatory for you?  If it's not, I think you would be better of with a solution using only functions, as such:

```
log(){
  echo "${2:-Log message}: ${1:-}"
}

log "all is fine"
# Log message: all is fine
log "drama!" "Error message"
# Error message: drama!
```

Of course, you can make it more expressive with another function on top:

```
error(){
  log "${1:-}" "Error message"
}

log "all is fine"
# Log message: all is fine
error "drama!"
# Error message: drama!
```

Hope this helps.  If you really need redirections ('>') let me know and I will dig deeper.